# JavaScript not rounding date properly

Tags: javascript, date

```js
//Expected: 2016-04-01 Actual: 2016-04-01
console.log(roundToQuarter(new Date("2016-05-30T23:39:35.418Z")));

//Expected: 2016-04-01 Actual: 2016-05-01
console.log(roundToQuarter(new Date("2016-05-31T00:21:55.875Z"))); 

//Expected: 2016-04-01 Actual: 2016-04-01
console.log(roundToQuarter(new Date("2016-06-10T00:11:22.124Z"))); 

function roundToQuarter( date ) {
 var monthIndex = Math.floor( date.getUTCMonth() / 3 );
 date.setUTCHours ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
 date.setUTCMonth( monthIndex * 3 );
 date.setUTCDate( 1 );

 return date.toISOString();
}
```

I have written a script that takes an ISO date string and rounds it to the start of each quarter (1/1, 4/1, 7/1, 10/1).

I have found this odd edge case that affects seemingly arbitrary date ranges, and I cannot figure out why it is not rounding correctly. In this particular instance, it is rounding the entire day (5/31) to (5/1) when it should round to (4/1). This occurs at other dates too.

Comment: In the second example, when you set the month to be `April` by doing `setUTCMonth`, that line effectively changes the date to `2016-04-31`, right? The problem: April does not have 31 days. JS thinks it's doing you a favor, and changes April 31st to *May 1st*.

Comment: Set the date before the month.

Answer (score 1):

As Tyler Roper and Xufox have suggested in comments, the date should be set before the month. If you change the month first, it will probably clash with the date as the new month may not have such date. That's the case for your second example. If the date is change to 1 first, then changing month afterwards is easy.

```
function roundToQuarter( date ) {
    date.setUTCHours ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    date.setUTCDate( 1 );
    date.setUTCMonth( Math.floor( date.getUTCMonth() / 3 ) * 3 );

    return date.toISOString();
}
```

Comment: You can set the month and date at the same time: `date.setUTCMonth(month, date)` where *month* and *date* can be an expressions.